# Best way to generate a function that generates a function in C#

Tags: c#, f#, functional-programming

F# provides a feature, where a function can return another function.

An example of function generating a function in F# is:

```ml
let powerFunctionGenarator baseNumber = (fun exponent -> baseNumber ** exponent);

let powerOfTwo = powerFunctionGenarator 2.0;

let powerOfThree = powerFunctionGenarator 3.0;

let power2 = powerOfTwo 10.0;
let power3 = powerOfThree 10.0;

printfn "%f" power2;
printfn "%f" power3;
```

The best way I could come up with to achieve the same in C# was this:

```cs
class Program
{
    delegate double PowerOf2(double exponent);
    delegate double PowerOf3(double exponent);
    delegate double PowerOfN(double n, double exponent);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PowerOfN powerOfN = (a, b) => { return Math.Pow(a,b) ; };
        PowerOf2 powerOf2 = (a) => { return powerOfN(2, a); };
        PowerOf3 powerOf3 = (a) => { return powerOfN(3, a); };

        double result = powerOf2(10);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        result = powerOf3(10);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Is there some other way (/better way) of doing this?

Comment: I've never done that much currying in C#, but doesn't lambdas kinda limit the usefulness of currying? @Ngm; what is your reason for generating methods on the fly?

Comment: No particular reason, just wanted to explore how it could be done.

Comment: Note that all functions are curried in F#, so you could have equivalently written `powerFunctionGenerator` as `let powerFunctionGenarator baseNumber exponent = baseNumber ** exponent`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, that's straightforward in C#:

```
using System;
class P
{
  static void Main()
  {
      Func<double, Func<double, double>> powerFunctionGenerator = 
          baseNumber => exponent => Math.Pow(baseNumber, exponent);  

      Func<double, double> powerOfTwo = powerFunctionGenerator(2.0);
      Func<double, double> powerOfThree = powerFunctionGenerator(3.0);
      double power2 = powerOfTwo(10.0); 
      double power3 = powerOfThree(10.0);
      Console.WriteLine(power2); 
      Console.WriteLine(power3);
  }
}
```

Easy peasy. And if you don't like the manifest typing, most of those can be replaced with `var`.

Comment: You could also have the function as a parameter: `Func<double, Func<double, double, double>, Func<double, double>> functionGenerator = (a, f) => b => f(a, b); var powOf2 = functionGenerator(2, PowerFunction);`

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you ever seen some C# code that uses this to solve some practical task? I wrote my `Curry`/`Uncurry` functions in C# too, but it feels that the syntax would be just too confusing...

Comment: @TomasPetricek: Sure; for example, I once wrote an implementation of the A* pathfinding algorithm. The algorithm in general needs a function that can estimate the distance between two points, but for any particular run of the algorithm it needs a function that can estimate the distance between any point and one fixed point. You can use partial application to achieve that.

Comment: @EricLippert That definitely sounds like a nice application for partial function application. The reason why I'm not too convinced about using this in C# is that a declaration like `Point[] AStar(Point[] points, Func<Point, Func<Point, float>> metric)` is about 70 characters long. Not very netbook friendly :-).

Answer (score 6):

You could write a function to curry another function. The inconvenience is that you would have to create all the overloads you need.

An example:

```
using System;

class Program {

    static Func<T2, TRes> Curry<T1, T2, TRes>(Func<T1, T2, TRes> f, T1 t1) {
        return (t2) => f(t1, t2);
    }

    static double PowerFunction(double d1, double d2) {
        return Math.Pow(d1, d2);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var powerOf2 = Curry<double, double, double>(PowerFunction, 2);
        double r = powerOf2(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: I will have to explore more about "Curry". Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3):

Almost literal translation of your original F# to C#:

```
Func<double,Func<double,double>> powerFunctionGenerator = 
    (baseNumber) => ((exponent) => Math.Pow(baseNumber, exponent));

var powerOfTwo = powerFunctionGenarator(2.0);

var powerOfThree = powerFunctionGenarator(3.0);

var power2 = powerOfTwo(10.0);
var power3 = powerOfThree(10.0);

Console.WriteLine(power2);
Console.WriteLine(power3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you're asking is how to rewrite `powerFunctionGenarator` into C#, you can do it in a pretty straightforward way:

```
Func<double, double> powerFunctionGenarator(double baseNumber)
{
    return exponent => Math.Pow(baseNumber, exponent);
}
```

You can't put the method declaration like this in inside another method in C#. But if you want to do that, you can use lambda in a lambda, as sblom suggested:

```
Func<double, Func<double, double>> powerFunctionGenerator =
    baseNumber => exponent => Math.Pow(baseNumber, exponent);
```

Which is equivalent to the following code in F#:

```
let powerFunctionGenarator = fun baseNumber -> (fun exponent -> baseNumber ** exponent)
```